# How do I validate a URL path with a wildcard in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

str = `'http://*.foo.com/bar/'` is a valid string.

How do I write a regex to validate this in JavaScript?

```
`http://xyz.foo.com/bar/`     ✓ valid
`http://xyz.foo.com/bar/abc/` ✗ invalid
`http://xyz.foo.com/`         ✗ invalid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try playing around at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It has a lot of good information and will give you a javascript regex at the bottom of the page when you are done.

Try this:

```
var url = // your url
url.match(/http://[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\.foo\.com/bar/$/g)
```

The `$` matches the end of a string. The `$` at the end will make sure that there is no text after it.

Comment: replace xyz with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more details?

e,g, `/^http://[a-zA-Z]+.foo.com/bar/$/g`

will do what you're looking for if it is on a single line (through ^$ delimiters). It will match xyz but not xyz1 which is easy to fix if you want to include numbers.

Play around it and let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: you need to escape your periods

Answer (score 0):

You can assign some of the `location` object's properties to your own variables once the page loads (since `location` is free to change afterward):

```
var hostURL = location.host;    //should be '*.foo.com'
var pathURL = location.pathname;    //should be '/bar'
```

Then create a RegExp object:

```
var regex = '.*\.foo\.com/bar/$';
var testURL = new RegExp(regex);
```

And test the URL:

```
if (testURL(hostURL + pathURL)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex oughta do it for you.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov)\b
```

Assign the above to a variable. And test if this pattern matches with the url of your choice using test() method of javascript. Update this to suit your needs if need be.